# 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'std::vector<long unsigned int>&'

Tags: c++11, constants

I had a c++11 project on linux where i used the following signature which fails to compile on linux but compiles on windows

Error:

```
error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'std::vector<long unsigned int>&'

error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'std::map<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>&'
```

Function was

```
    bool debugGlobalDs(std::vector<size_t> & const elementIds ,
 std::map<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>& const mapElementIdToGlobalIndex)
    {
    ....
    return true
    }
```

Why cant I use const qualifier here? Once I remove it, it compiles fine on Linux too.

Comment: You can’t have const references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` is in the wrong place. It should be `const std::vector<size_t>& elementIds`.
This means that the function is not allowed to change `elementIds`.

The same is the case with the `map` as well.
It should be `const std::map<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>& mapElementIdToGlobalIndex`

Where `const` is placed in the OP marks the reference as `const`. As references cannot be changed anyway there is no need to do this.

Comment: Its read from right to left . I want to make elementIds as const so that they cant be changed.  Putting const at first means elementIds is a ref to a vector which is const .

Comment: You will not be able to change `elementIds` even with this. See demo: https://godbolt.org/z/b4pY_a.

Comment: @MAG: Correct.  But there is no way to make a reference `const`, because there are no operations which mutate a reference to begin with, so none to disable.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for your comment.  It cleared the answer more.